# swing full screen shortcut

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a `JMenuItem` which has an Accelerator of `shift + f11`.
by pressing `shift + f11` or clicking on `JMenuItem` it must get fullScreen.

does anyone have any advice?

```
JMenuItem toggle_full_screenFull = new JMenuItem("Toggle Full Screen");
toggle_full_screenFull.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F11 , InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
public class FullScreenExample extends JFrame {
    public FullScreenExample() {
        super("");

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu homeMenu = new JMenu("home");

        JMenuItem fullScreen = new JMenuItem("full screen");
        fullScreen.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F11, KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
        fullScreen.addActionListener(e->setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH));
        homeMenu.add(fullScreen);

        menuBar.add(homeMenu);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new FullScreenExample().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

And it works either with `KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK` or `KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK`.

Now, if you want to make it function like enable/disable full screen mode:

```
fullScreen.addActionListener(e -> {
    boolean isNormal = getExtendedState() == JFrame.NORMAL;
    setExtendedState(isNormal ? JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH : JFrame.NORMAL);
});
```

Comment: thanks that really helped. can I do something like if I press it again it goes back to normal?

Comment: @bizzaro33 I have edited my answer, but please next time mention it in your original question.